# Cannot add email login if already have Google login

Tags: bug, login, google, openid, network-profile

I currently use Google to login to SO. I would like to add an email login in 2022.

Other questions on meta and other metas discuss older versions of SO and the switch from OpenID which was many years ago. So I have opened a new question to document the current issue.

Here is a recording of the issue.

https://youtu.be/A_42F5O8f4E

In this video you can so I also have an OpenID login at phor.net. After recording the video, I have also removed that OpenID login and proceeded with the same results.

The result of using the ADD MORE LOGINS button and adding an email login is that no such email is added to the account.

Answer (score 7):

You already have another account registered with the email you are trying to add to your account. Normally when this happens, we try to automatically merge them together for you. But since you have a high reputation, the automated system backs off and waits for approval from staff to complete the merge.

I've gone ahead and approved the merge, but you'll still need to use the Add more logins button again to finish adding the credential to your account. It was only attached to the other account as a verified email and not a credential.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Am I safe now to remove the Google login or will that mess up my other Stack Exchange accounts?

Comment: You are fine to remove it if you don't want it attached.